# Rails: Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a button_to tag in my show.html.erb file.

```
  <%= link_to 'Click HERE to open file', @user.image.url  %><br/><br/><br/>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Parse CSV File:") %><br/>
<%= button_to 'Parse CSV', {:controller => "users_controller", :action => "process" } %>
  <% end %>
```

Then I have this added to my users_controller.rb file

```
# GET /users/1/process
def process
 puts 'To be Implemented'
end
```

Im getting an error in the routing file

```
No route matches [POST] "/assets"
```

This is how my routing file looks:

```
resources :users

resources :listings
```

What should I change. Im a bit confused, woould really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your route and define like this

```
<%= button_to 'Parse CSV', {:controller => "users", :action => "process" } %>
```

Then in route file

```
    resources :users do
      collection do
         get: process
     end
    end
```

It will sure work

Comment: Thanks for your response but I wish to correct something here the line "get: process" dosen't it should be: "get :process"

Answer (score 0):

1) In view, use the controller name like 'users', not the 'users_controller' .

```
<%= button_to 'Parse CSV', {:controller => "users", :action => "process" } %>
```

2) rails define few routes by default , but for other you need to define yourself .
Declare the routes like :

```
  resources :users do
    :member => {
     :process => :get
    }
  end
```

Hope that help .

Comment: Don't edit the part about `users_controller` in the question!! Maybe that is the problem and other users won't be able to help if you edit that out.